# jQuery create select options using loop

Tags: jquery

Im trying to create select box using jquery but the links populates randomly so I need to loops thru links and grab it to make select box, here is my code any idea how to use a short hand/loop? Thanks

HTML:

```
<p>
    <a href="#">option1</a>
    <a href="#">option2</a>
    <a href="#">option3</a>
</p>

<select  id="select"></select>
```

JS:

```
$.fn.populate = function() {
    var option1 = $('p a:eq(0)').text();
    var option2 = $('p a:eq(1)').text();
    var option3 = $('p a:eq(2)').text();
  $(this)
    .append('<option value="">' + option1 + '</option>')
    .append('<option value="">' + option2 + '</option>')
    .append('<option value="">' + option3 + '</option>')
}

$('#select').populate();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QgCqE/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var $this = $(this);

$('p a').each(function(){
    $this.append('<option value="">' + $(this).text() + '</option>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QgCqE/1/

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/RY3U9/4/

```
var selectbox=$("#select");//cache our slectbox, so jquery doesn't have to look for it in every loop.

$('p > a').each(function(){//select all a tags in p (loop through them)
    var text=$(this).text();//cache the link text in a variable because we need it twice.
    selectbox.append($('<option>').text(text).val(text));//add new option with value en text to selectbox
})
```

Answer (score 4):

A **Cleaner and more jQuery-oriented solution** of *James Montagne*'s answer:

```
$this.append( $('<option/>').val('').text($(this).text()) );
```

or the alternative with properties mapping:

```
$this.append($("<option/>", {
    value: '',
    text: $(this).text()
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#new_organizations').click(loadOrgTypes);

function loadOrgTypes() {

  console.log('retrieving all Org Types');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: rootURL+'org_types',
    dataType: "json", // data type of response
    success: renderOrgTypes,

     error: function(err){
       console.log('Error');
       console.log("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                        }

  });
}


function renderOrgTypes(data){
 var list = data == null ? [] : (data instanceof Array ? data : [data]);

 var select = $("#org_types_select");
    select.empty();

 $.each(list , function(index, org_types) {
            var content='<option org_type_id="' + org_types.id + '">' + org_types.name_loc + '</option>';
            select.append(content);

 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for a function unless you are planning to use it for sever drop downs.

```
var ddl = $("#select");

$("p a").each(function () {
    var link = $(this);
    ddl.append($("<option></option>").val(link.text()).html(link.text()));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the loop in your elements use [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

---

You dont need extend jQuery unless you want to make it reusable.

<kbd>[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pT6rs/)</kbd>

```
$.fn.populate = function(el) {
    var options = '';
    $(el).each(function(i, e) {
       options += '<option>' + $(this).text() + '</option>'; 
    });
    this.append(options);
    return this;
}

$('#select').populate('p > a');
```